# Upload Code to Arduino UNO with a C# Form

Tags: c#, upload, arduino

I build a project in C# with which one can control a RGB led. My goal is to build a function in which one can upload code that controls the LED. Therefore I need help with the following proble :

There is a button and a rich text box on the form. The text of the rich text box contains source code, which should get uploaded to the arduino if you press the button. I know how to open the port but i dont know how to upload the source code.

My code :

```
namespace RGBLedColorPicker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        private Color defaultColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                port.Open();
                this.SetColor(defaultColor);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cant find Arduino.Closing programm");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor(defaultColor);
            port.Close();
        }

        private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void SetColor(Color color)
        {
            port.Write(new[] { color.R, color.G, color.B }, 0, 3);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor(Color.Red);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor(Color.Green);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor(Color.Blue);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor(Color.Red);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.SetColor(Color.Green);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            this.SetColor(Color.Blue);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            MessageBox.Show("Show beendet","beendet",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            this.SetColor(defaultColor);
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Create f2 = new Create())
            {
                f2.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor(defaultColor);
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                SetColor(colorDialog1.Color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? I don't think that you can upload code via the serial port and then execute it on the arduino (but in this I'm probably wrong). Yet why don't you just develop an application that runs on the arduino that listens for incoming serial port data, and then translate this data into commands to execute (like changing the LED color).

Comment: I try to build a program to controll a RGB-Led . And the arduino needs a code . Else you cant run this src. And i want to build a form who the code in a rich text stands. And under the text box is a button where you can upload the code

Comment: Have you read the [basic How-To](https://www.arduino.cc/en/main/howto)? This explains how to copy code to your Arduino. You do not have to copy the code from your C# application to the Arduino, you do this within the IDE in which you develop your Arduino code. Or am I missing something here? Why do you want to have the code within the C# application?